# Obtaining EMC measurment equipment

Tags: emc, emi-filtering, certification

I am an electronics engineering graduate who works on developing  the electronics for an EV charger. We are now in the process of slowly getting ready to get the product certified, which includes EMC testing. I have a reasonable understanding about EMC and its measurement and steps to take to minimize EMI, however I have no practical experience with a real product. Currently the company doesn't have any EMI measurement equipment other then digital oscilloscopes.

What sort of equipment should I consider purchasing for the company to get in order to pass EMC testing? I was thinking about obtaining a LISN and a spectral analyzer and perhaps some near field E and H probes, however that equipment is already at minimum a couple thousand dollars. Is there an alternative like leasing equipment or going to a 3rd party lab that has cheaper rates then a notifying body laboratory?

How would someone go through EMC compliance when starting from scratch?

Comment: Asking what to buy is off topic, but the part how to pass EMC tests is a valid question. Of course you can lease equipment or do pre-tests at a suitable lab that provides such services.

Comment: Usually you acquire a cheap (i.e. used) analyzer for preliminary thing and then go to a lab for the full tests. Doing in home is expensive even if you rent and you'll need almost a full room with sub-optimal results. Also depends on *which* EMC part are you focusing on: radiated fields are the more complicated but ESD it trivial once you have the zap gun

Answer (score 2):

This is an expensive and complicated process to set up and do right.  Sounds like this is a one-off product (maybe with follow-ons). Unless you're planning on having to do this on many products over many years, I would recommend contracting with an outside lab that specializes in EMC testing.